# MongoDB - string list to object list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a colleccion with a string list:

```
{
"_id" : "87df7fd8f7df",
"spaces" : [ 
    "45dfsdf5646sdf44fd", 
    "5d4fdf885sahg6f6fg"
],
}
```

and i tried to replace with a object list like this:

```
{
"_id" : "ytry45rty4r4y",
"spaces" : [ 
{
    "id" : "123",
    "role" : ""
}, 
{
    "id" : "321",
    "role" : ""
}, 
}
```

Please help me to create a script.

Comment: Please provide more information. Do you want just blindly replace?

Comment: Do you want to use each string in the array as id and lease the role empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is to run something like this in mongo shell.
The question was not clear enough to understand what mapping you want to do but in general code is going to look like this:

```js
db.testCollection.find().snapshot().forEach(function (elem) {
 if (!(elem && elem.spaces && elem.spaces.length && typeof elem.spaces[0] === 'string')) {
  print('Unable to update object: ' + elem._id.toString());

  return;
 }

 var spaceObjects = elem.spaces.map(function (string) {
  return {
   id: string,
   role: ''
  };
 });

 db.testCollection.update({_id: elem._id},
  {
   $set: {spaces: spaceObjects}
  }
 );
});
```